# What is an ‘`is` value’ of a DOM element node?

Tags: dom, web-component, native-web-component

While idly browsing the DOM specification, I came upon [this passage](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-element-is-value):

> Elements have an associated namespace, namespace prefix, local name, custom element state, custom element definition, **`is` value**. When an element is created, all of these values are initialized.

Looking at other parts of the specification, I learned that it is apparently supposed to be a string value or null. However, I have not been able to find out what is it actually supposed to be used *for*.

Of what use is this concept?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/is

Answer (score 0):

The `is` attribute usage relates to native [web components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Components) (think react, just native to the HTML spec).

It allows you to create a custom component that behaves like a native HTML component as explained [in the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/is):

```js
// Create a class for the element
class WordCount extends HTMLParagraphElement {
  constructor() {
    // Always call super first in constructor
    super();

    // Constructor contents omitted for brevity
    // …
  }
}

// Define the new element
customElements.define("word-count", WordCount, { extends: "p" });
```

```html
<p is="word-count"></p>
```

It is however not implemented in Safari browser as Apple has principled objections to its use as discussed in [the thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72090155/what-web-component-features-are-not-supported-by-safari-desktop-and-safari-ios).