# What web component features are not supported by Safari desktop and Safari iOS?

Tags: safari, mobile-safari, web-component

Most references as below mention that Safari partially supports web components.

In detail, what web component features are not supported by Safari desktop and Safari iOS?

Is there a technical docs or specs about the issue?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components

https://caniuse.com/shadowdomv1

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> *Burn all old blogs!*

**Apple Safari supports Web Components**, apart from ***Customized Built-In** Elements*.

After an ongoing debate since **2013**, nearly everyone, who understand what OOP means, agrees Apple engineers are right on this one, **not** supporting Customized Built-In Elements

#### NOT SUPPORTED in Safari:

[***Customized Built-In*** Elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/define#customized_built-in_element)
extend from any **existing** HTML Element: `<p>, <input>, etc..`

```
customElements.define(
  "my-element",
  HTMLParagraphElement,
  {
    extends: "p",
  },
);
```

If you want to understand the Apple Why,
read back in time [to early December **2013**](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webapps/2013OctDec/0801.html) - Yes! Web Components are ***not*** a new fad!

---

Yes it would be cool to write `<img is="queen-of-hearts">` (generating an IMG)
We now have to do with `<playing-card is="queen-of-hearts">`
which generates a `<playing-code>` tag with *another* `<img>` tag inside of it.

#### SUPPORTED in Safari:

***Autonomous* Elements** (extend from `HTMLElement`)
**work 100% in all Modern Browsers**

```
customElements.define( "my-element", extends HTMLElement{ } );
```

For Framework compatibility see: https://custom-elements-everywhere.com/
(React is the odd one out)

Deep dive into Web Components, React & Lit like BaseClasses:
[Main differences between lit-element Web Components & React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64304353/main-differences-between-lit-element-react/64307820#64307820)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript regexp variable length lookbehind is not supported by Safari but works in Chrome, Edge and Firefox.  Maybe international agreements/standards say Safari doesn't need to support it (yet) but it's a pain nonetheless.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The forum post (see below) on the Apple Developer website has both requests to support customized built-in elements and formAssociated custom elements.

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682165

It could be used to follow up onto when Apple will release support for those features on Safari.