Insert a table row with custom web components
I'm learning how to use custom Web components. I try to create a table row with a custom component. Here is the HTML:
<table border="2">
    <tbody>
        <table-row></table-row>
        <table-row></table-row>
    </tbody>
</table>

Here is the JavaScript:
// Create a class for the element
class TableRow extends HTMLElement {

  constructor() {
    // Always call super first in constructor
    super();
  }

  connectedCallback() {
        let tr = document.createElement('tr')
        let td = document.createElement('td')
        td.textContent = "Row content";
        tr.append(td);
        this.append(tr);
  }
}

customElements.define("table-row", TableRow);

Here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Imabot/c92fye8d/1/
As you can see, it does not work as expected.
Am I doing something wrong?
Generally speaking, when building a custom component, should we fill or replace the custom tags <table-row></table-row>?


// Create a class for the element
class TableRow extends HTMLElement {

  constructor() {
    // Always call super first in constructor
    super();
  }

  connectedCallback() {
        let tr = document.createElement('tr')
        let td = document.createElement('td')
        td.textContent = "Row content";
        tr.append(td);
        this.append(tr);
  }
}

customElements.define("table-row", TableRow);
<table border="2">
    <tbody>
        <table-row></table-row>
        <table-row></table-row>
    </tbody>
</table>




Part of the problem that I see is table-row isn't an allowed child of tbody. So on page load, table-row automatically gets put outside of the table altogether. So when your code modifies the table-row, its just modifying the code outside of the tbody. Maybe try dynamically creating the tbody and then adding your rows to it as children.

<table-row> should be <tr> ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody scroll down to "Permitted content"

you cannot use custom tags in a table and its also not recommended to do so.
What u can do is to define a  as a custom row like in this example:


class CustomTableRow extends HTMLTableRowElement {
  constructor() {
    super(); // Always call super first in constructor
    // Your custom initialization
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    let td = document.createElement('td');
    td.textContent = "Row content";
    this.appendChild(td);
  }
}

customElements.define('custom-table-row', CustomTableRow, { extends: 'tr' });
<table border="2">
    <tbody>
        <tr is="custom-table-row"></tr>
        <tr is="custom-table-row"></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>




Thank you. I'm impressed! What is the is keyword in the tag ? Is it a native HTML keyword?

yes it is native HTML keyword but only supported in modern Browsers. Its a part of the "Custome Elements specification" or something like that which came up in 2016

And.. Custumized Built In Elements will never be implemented by Apple/Safari.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72090155/what-web-component-features-are-not-supported-by-safari-desktop-and-safari-ios/72090672#72090672
