Instantiating custom built-in element in JavaScript does not work
I've crafted a custom built-in element that recursively invokes itself. However, the child elements generated in JavaScript are not inheriting from the custom built-in element. Given that the initial invocation from HTML is functioning correctly, I suspect the issue may stem from the page lifecycle when adding controls via JavaScript. Any thoughts on why this could be occurring?
html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <ul is="test-list" id="testList">

    </ul>
    <script type="module" src="/js/test-list-element.js"></script>

    <script>
        let data = [
            {
                name: 'a',
                data: [{
                    name: 'a',
                    data: []
                },
                {
                    name: 'b',
                    data: []
                },
                {
                    name: 'c',
                    data: []
                },
                {
                    name: 'd',
                    data: []
                }]
            },
            {
                name: 'b',
                data: [{
                    name: 'a',
                    data: []
                },
                {
                    name: 'b',
                    data: []
                },
                {
                    name: 'c',
                    data: []
                },
                {
                    name: 'd',
                    data: []
                }]
            },
            {
                name: 'c',
                data: [{
                    name: 'a',
                    data: []
                },
                {
                    name: 'b',
                    data: []
                },
                {
                    name: 'c',
                    data: []
                },
                {
                    name: 'd',
                    data: []
                }]
            },
            {
                name: 'd',
                data: [{
                    name: 'a',
                    data: []
                },
                {
                    name: 'b',
                    data: []
                },
                {
                    name: 'c',
                    data: []
                },
                {
                    name: 'd',
                    data: []
                }]
            },
        ];

        window.onload = (event) => {
            let listElement = document.getElementById("testList");
            listElement.data = data;
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>

test-list-element.js
class testList extends HTMLUListElement {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.render = this.render.bind(this);
    }
  
    #data = null;
    set data(value) {
      this.#data = value;
      this.render();
    }

    render(){
        if(!this.#data) return;

        this.#data.forEach(element => {
            let newItem = document.createElement('li');
            newItem.innerText = element.name;
            this.appendChild(newItem);

            if(element.data)
            {
                let newlist = document.createElement('ul');
                newlist.setAttribute('is','test-list')            
                newlist.data = data;
                newItem.appendChild(newlist);
            }
        });
    }
}

    
customElements.define('test-list', testList, { extends: 'ul' });
  



I have tested this code in Chrome, Firefox, and Edge

And had you tested Safari it would have failed. CBIE is, and never will be supported in Apple/Safari: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72090155/what-web-component-features-are-not-supported-by-safari-desktop-and-safari-ios/72090672#72090672

Have you tried let newlist = new TestList() instead of let newlist = document.createElement('ul'); newlist.setAttribute('is','test-list')?

@Bergi, Thank you. That was worked and was obvious after you said it. I should have tried it sooner. If you will write your comment as an answer, I will give you credit.

It will still not work in Safari...

@Danny'365CSI'Engelman I don't need it to work in Safari. Apple can choose how to limit their browsers and their customers can choose to be limited. This is why we have multiple browsers. I am program to standards.

Don't use
const newlist = document.createElement('ul');
newlist.setAttribute('is','test-list');

to create the element, as the is part must be present on construction time; setting it after construction has no effect.
The correct way to instantiate a custom element is either the createElement options parameter
const newlist = document.createElement('ul', {is: 'test-list'});

or just the constructor itself:
const newlist = new TestList();

