Is it possible to create a Web Component that can extend any element?
I want to create a custom element class that can be use on basically any type of element if is="foo-element" is present, but I get the feeling that it's not possible.
The closest I have been able to come up with is this abomination.
const allTags = ["ul", "div" /* etc... */]
for (const tag of allTags) {
    const baseCalss = document.createElement(tag).constructor
    const customElement = class extends baseCalss {
        constructor() { super() }
    }
    customElements.define("custom-element-"+tag, customElement, { extends: tag })
}

<ul is="custom-element-ul">

</ul>

<div is="custom-element-div">

</div>


What are you trying to do? It might not be standard but you still can put custom attributes on any tags. It is recommended to prefix your custom attributes with data- : data-is="..."

@HaoWu An example use case was the idea of being able to define a "selection" element that when is="selection-element" is added would cause any direct child to adopt a selected attribute when clicked, and then you could have a property to return the selected child, etc. In hindsight, it seems like this probably wasn't what Web Components was intended for, and maybe I am better off just using old-fashioned ad hoc javascript augmentation functions.

Yes, you make this work on Chromium and FireFox; it just will never work in Safari: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72090155/what-web-component-features-are-not-supported-by-safari-desktop-and-safari-ios/72090672#72090672

@Danny'365CSI'Engelman good to know that part of the spec was never fully adopted.
